# Generify filtering in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm trying to generify the filtering process to be able to apply filters on any of my entities.

**Using some code online I build this:**

```
public enum FilterOperation {
    // @formatter:off
    LESS_EQUAL_THAN("<=", CriteriaBuilder::lessThanOrEqualTo),
    GREATER_EQUAL_THAN(">=", CriteriaBuilder::greaterThanOrEqualTo),
    CONTAINS(":>", CriteriaBuilder::like),
    GREATER_THAN(">", CriteriaBuilder::greaterThan),
    LESS_THAN("<", CriteriaBuilder::lessThan),
    EQUALS("::", CriteriaBuilder::equal);
    // @formatter:on

    private final String operationName;
    private final FilterPredicateFunction operation;

    private static Pattern separator = Pattern.compile("([\\S\\s]+)§([\\S\\s]+)");

    FilterOperation(String operationName, FilterPredicateFunction operation) {
        this.operationName = operationName;
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    public String getOperationName() {
        return operationName;
    }

    public Predicate build(CriteriaBuilder builder, Root<?> entity, String key, String value) {
        // Split value by character §
        Matcher m = separator.matcher(value);
        if (m.matches()) {
            String type = m.group(2);
            if (type.equals("UUID")) {
                return builder.equal(entity.get(key), UUID.fromString(m.group(1)));
            } else {
                throw new WrongFilterException("Filter operation not found");
            }
        } else {
            // No § found we expect a string search
            return operation.predicate(builder, entity.get(key), value.toString());
        }
    }

    static FilterOperation parse(String str) {
        for (FilterOperation filter : FilterOperation.values()) {
            if (str.equals(filter.getOperationName())) {
                return filter;
            }
        }

        throw new WrongFilterException(String.format("Filter operation not found", str));
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    interface FilterPredicateFunction {
        Predicate predicate(CriteriaBuilder builder, Path<String> key, String value);
    }
}
```

**Here is an example of URL with filtering:**

```
http://localhost:8080/api/type/284c5f72-559d-4e62-a316-6bd23259c213/slot/filter?filter=name:>Samedi&filter=id::773f7313-0f37-4465-a707-7295c2bb87a3§UUID
```

As you can see I have two cases, one with only a field, an operation, and the value `name:>Samedi` and a second case where I add the type with a separator character: `id::773f7313-0f37-4465-a707-7295c2bb87a3§UUID`

**Just to precise, another class call my build function like this:**

```
return (Specification<T>) (root, query, cb) -> op.build(cb, root, key, value);
```

With for example key as `'id'` and value as `'773f7313-0f37-4465-a707-7295c2bb87a3§UUID'`

In my code actually, I use the `builder.equal` function to create Predicates for my custom type (here UUID) and not the operation defined at the beginning of my enum, but now I want to add the support for the `LocalTime` type and use the right operation to be able to use a `greaterThan` or less than.

```
 if (type.equals("UUID")) {
     return builder.equal(entity.get(key), UUID.fromString(m.group(1)));
 } else {
     throw new WrongFilterException("Filter operation not found");
 }
```

**To this:**

```
if (type.equals("UUID")) {
  return operation.predicate(builder, entity.get(key), UUID.fromString(m.group(1)));
} else {
  throw new WrongFilterException("Filter operation not found");
}
```

**But then I have this error:**

```
Required type: String Provided: UUID
```

Obviously, that error came from my `FilterPredicateFunction` that can only take a String, I try to change it to object but then all my `CriteriaBuilder::methodName` get this error: `Cannot resolve method 'greaterThanOrEqualTo'`

What can I do to use any operation on any type of data?
Any idea on how I can achieve this?

**EDIT:**
**I add all other class that I use to better understand the process:**

```
public class EntitySpecificationBuilder<T> {

    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
    public static <T> Optional<Specification<T>> parse(List<String> filters) {
        if (filters == null || filters.isEmpty()) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }

        List<Specification> criterias = mapSpecifications(filters);
        if (criterias.isEmpty()) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }

        Specification<T> root = Specification.where(criterias.get(0));
        for (int index = 1; index < criterias.size(); index++) {
            root = Specification.where(root).and(criterias.get(index));
        }
        return Optional.of(root);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    private static <T> List<Specification> mapSpecifications(List<String> filters) {
        return filters.stream().map(str -> {
            for (FilterOperation op : FilterOperation.values()) {
                int index = str.indexOf(op.getOperationName());
                if (index > 0) {
                    String key = str.substring(0, index);
                    String value = str.substring(index + op.getOperationName().length());

                        return (Specification<T>) (root, query, cb) -> op.build(cb, root, key, value);

                }
            }

            return null;
        }).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

The builder:

```
public class FindAllBuilder<E, R extends PagingAndSortingRepository<E, ?> & JpaSpecificationExecutor<E>> {

    private final R repository;

    private Specification<E> filters;

    private Sort sort = Sort.unsorted();

    public static <E, R extends PagingAndSortingRepository<E, ?> & JpaSpecificationExecutor<E>> FindAllBuilder<E, R> usingRepository(
            R repository) {
        return new FindAllBuilder<>(repository);
    }

    private FindAllBuilder(R repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public Page<E> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        return repository.findAll(filters, pageable);
    }

    public FindAllBuilder<E, R> filterBy(List<String> listFilters) {
        Optional<Specification<E>> opFilters = EntitySpecificationBuilder.parse(listFilters);
        if (opFilters.isPresent()) {
            if (filters == null) {
                filters = Specification.where(opFilters.get());
            } else {
                filters = filters.and(opFilters.get());
            }
        }

        return this;
    }

    public FindAllBuilder<E, R> sortBy(String orderBy, String orderDir) {
        if (!orderBy.isEmpty()) {
            sort = Sort.by(Direction.fromOptionalString(orderDir).orElse(Direction.ASC), orderBy);
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

And how I call it in my controller:

```
FindAllBuilder.usingRepository(this.repository).filterBy(filters).findAll(pageable).map(MyMapper.INSTANCE::toDTO);
```

With filter as an array of string that looks like this: `name:>test`

**The awful way to do this would to transform my buildChild function to something like this:**

```
public Predicate buildChild(CriteriaBuilder builder, Root<?> entity, String pKey, String cKey, String value) {
    Matcher m = separator.matcher(value);
    if (m.matches()) {
        String type = m.group(2);
        if (type.equals("UUID")) {
            if(operationName.equals(FilterOperation.EQUALS.getOperationName())) {
                return builder.equal(entity.get(pKey).get(cKey), UUID.fromString(m.group(1)));
            } else if (operationName.equals(FilterOperation.CONTAINS.getOperationName())) {
                return builder.like(...);
            } etc...
            
        } else if (type.equals("LocalTime")) {
            ....
        }
        
        else {
            throw new WrongFilterException("Filter operation not found");
        }
    } else {
        // No § found we expect a string search
        return operation.predicate(builder, entity.get(pKey).get(cKey), value.toString());
    }
}
```

But I would have to implement for each type of data each type of operation, this will be a lot of ifs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to get what you are trying to achieve , but from first look , if your logic is fine but the function waits for **String** and you pass **UUID** , so Instead of casting it to **Object** why not to replace :

```
UUID.fromString(m.group(1))
```

with

```
m.group(1)
```

so you pass the same value but with **String** type , and if you are using

```
UUID.fromString()
```

to make sure the incoming string is in UUID format you can separate this validation step.

let me know if it works with you.

Comment: Yeah my Predicate function in the FunctionalInterface wait for a String but this is the problem, if I cast my UUID to string I'll have an error that looks like: Cannot compare UUID with string. I want to change this String to object to be able to pass any type of data but this make my CriteriaBuilder::method getting errors